# Excel Function Large with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help getting a function to work. I need to add a feature that will only run this function if column B2-B900 doesn't contain a zero. I'm not sure how to add the if statement.

```
=INDEX(DATA!$A2:$A900, MATCH(LARGE(DATA!$J2:$J900, 1), DATA!$J2:$J900, 0))
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try wrapping in:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B900,0)=0, . . . )
```